# Python: Communicating with device over UART using CP2102 module

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, putty, pyserial, uart

**Summarize the problem:**

Sending a command over serial to a connected device (an FM tuner) yields no response. The connection is open, I have verified the bitrate to be correct, and the device

**Describe what you've tried:**

I used the code below to write a command to the open port in hopes that it would return the expected information:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
print(ser.is_open)                   # make sure port is open

with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 38400, timeout=5) as ser:    #baud rate is 38400, 5 sec timeout
    ser.write(b'RET')                                           #write "RET" to device
    reads = ser.read(5)                                         #read data from device
    print(reads)                                                #print data
```

The commands and expected output are listed in the image below.

I also attempted using tio on a Raspberry Pi 4 and PuTTY on a Windows 10 machine.

**Describe expected and actual results:**

The expected result would be returned string with the properties mentioned in the table. However, the returned result is the following:

```
True
b''
```

This is informing me that the serial port is open, but no data is being received from "ser.read". No error messages were received.

Using tio, it opened a connection and displayed the following:

```
[tio 15:57:03] tio v1.32
[tio 15:57:03] Press ctrl-t q to quit
[tio 15:57:03] Connected
```

but then nothing after that.

PuTTY also did not show up anything when a connection was established.

[image: Chart of commands and expected outputs]

Comment: hello, you have several problems there. Can you post a link to the complete manual of the tuner? I can write an answer with some ideas but I prefer to take a look at the details first to make it as useful as possible.

Comment: @MarcosG. Here is a link to the manual: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/718OBATJDzL.pdf

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll take a look and write an answer as soon as possible. It should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite messed up. But let's first start debugging the serial port connection itself.

Even before that: a disclaimer. Your tuner's manual is of very bad quality so my answer is based on my best guesses when reading it. Bear that in mind if you decide to follow any of the advice and keep in mind that I cannot be blamed if nothing works or you destroy your product.

Now, let's get on with it. You don't explain how you are wiring your tuner to the serial port or how you are feeding the supply power. Assuming you are powering with the USB connector on the board I'm **guessing** the TTL voltage levels that the manual mentions will be 5 Volts (if you want to be completely sure you will --have to measure with a multimeter on the RX or TX pins to ground -GND- or study the circuit in detail, the picture on the manual has not enough resolution to give a good answer).

Assuming the TTL level is indeed 5 Volt you need to make sure your USB CP2102 module is also working on 5 Volt. Most of these modules do have a jumper to choose 5 or 3.3 Volt so make sure yours is in the right position (be aware that some devices intended for 5 Volts will work will 3.3 and vice-versa and others -in my experience not many of them- will be destroyed and will never work again).

Once the voltage for the serial lines is known you need to connect the wires. That's quite easy: GND on the CP2102 to GND on the tuner connector. TX on the CP2102 to RX on the tuner and RX on the CP2102 to TX on the tuner (yes, you read it right: RX to TX and TX to RX). After making these three connections properly double-check there is good contact and they will not come loose easily (if you have a multimeter it would be a good idea to check for continuity on each wire) you are ready for the software side.

At this point my advice would be to first try to get the connection up and running with `tio`, `minicom`, `puTTY` or any other terminal software of your liking. That would leave the code aside avoiding many problems.

If you use `tio` you can open a command line and type:

```
tio /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 38400 -e
```

Note that the `-e` option is to show the local echo (what you type). Now you will get the prompt you are already familiar with:

```
[tio 09:13:09] tio v1.32
[tio 09:13:09] Press ctrl-t q to quit
[tio 09:13:09] Connected
```

You can now type (you won't say anything on the screen until the end):

```
AT+RET
```

Then hit <kbd>INTRO</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (that means you keep <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and then hit <kbd>j</kbd>).

You should immediately get the current configuration, something like:

```
VOL=10
FRE=87.5
PLAY
BANK_OFF
```

If that works you should now be able to send other commands. For changing the tuning frequency to 90.0 Mhz you can type:

```
AT+FRE=900
```

<kbd>INTRO</kbd>  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

If, on the contrary, the tuner is not sending anything you might need to play with the command confirmation. Sometimes you need only a carriage return (if that's the case you should get the configuration right after you hit <kbd>INTRO</kbd>) or you simply need a new line character instead (try hitting  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> after the command, dropping the intro in between).

Finally, let's go to your pyserial code. On that front, you are making a couple of mistakes. First, you should not instantiate the port twice defining first the port with `ser=...` and then again with `with... as`. And next, you need to write the complete command: `AT+RET` instead of just `RET` (I don't know why they wrote A+RET on the table you included in your question, again: quality of the documentation is below zero).

You might also need to introduce a very short delay after you write the command and before you read on the port. That might be necessary for the device to prepare and send its answer. But that very much depends on how you set your port up. If you use a long enough reading timeout you should be ok.

Something as simple as the following should work:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=38400, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
stopbits=1, timeout=2, xonoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
command_to_send = "AT+RET\r\n"
ser.write(command_to_send.encode())
received = ser.read(128)
print(received)
```

The 128 bytes to read is just a large number that we are sure will be bigger than the real numbers you will receive, so the reading instruction should wait until the timeout is over (2 seconds) and then return all that it read, hopefully, the tuner's details).

Again, here you might need to play with the command, maybe you just need a CR `command_to_send = "AT+RET\r"` or you need both CR and NL.

Good luck and have lots of fun with your radio.

Comment: That was a fantastic response given the minimal documentation. I just had to modify your script minimally and I was able to get a response from the device. It would have also helped before if I had attached the 3.3v lead to power for the USB serial!

Comment: I'm glad what I wrote was useful. I'm not sure I get what you mean by connecting the 3.3V lead to power. You mean the 3.3V pin on the CP2102? and you connect it to a 3.3V power supply? As far as I know, you should not need to connect the 3.3V on the CP2102 anywhere. That pin is supposed to be used to give power to another device, and it seems you tuner does not need any more power if you are connecting it through USB. Of course I'm not sure how your particular CP2102 looks like...

Comment: I withdraw my comment about the power requirements. I had thought that might have been an issue since the manufacturer used either the 3.3v (which is what the voltage the UART uses) or the 5v, but I unplugged it and there was no issues with communication.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Anyway, have fun with it